# TextView still getting clicked though animated to hide

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-animation

I'm having a `TextView` which is animated to slide out on click. Now when I again click the area where `TextView` was layout the click event is still getting fired as if `TextView` is still there. I want the `TextView` to behave as if it's not there once hidden through animation.

Following are my animation files.

*res/anim/slide_out.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.0" />

</set>
```

*res/anim/slide_in.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />

</set>
```

Following is my *layout xml*.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/anim_tv"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#8800ff00"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And following is `Activity` code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView animTV;

    Animation animSlideIn;
    Animation animSlideOut;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        animTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.anim_tv);

        animTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                hide();

            }
        });

        // load the animation
        animSlideIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in);
        animSlideOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out);

        show();     
    }

    private void show() {           
        animTV.startAnimation(animSlideIn);         
    }

    private void hide() {
        animTV.startAnimation(animSlideOut);            
    }

}
```

Can anybody suggest a solution to this issue?

Thanks,

Ammar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @blackbelt suggestion I did following update in `Activity`.

```
 animSlideOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {  }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            animTV.setVisibility( View.GONE );
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }
    });
```

@blackbelt solution was partially helpful. To make it fully working I had to updated the `slide_out.xml` to set the `android:fillAfter` attribute to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

you can implements `Animation.AnimationListener`, and when `onAnimationEnd` is called you can change the `TextView`'s visibility to gone

Comment: Okay. After this update, the click on `TextView` is not fired. But there is another issue introduces. In my actual layout, I've `Button`s beneath the overlayed by animated `TextView`. Now though the animated `TextView` is not visible anymore, still those `Button`s not working as if there is something above them. Any idea?

Comment: probably you forgot to call setOnClickListener on the button's instance,

Comment: Nops. The issue was with `android:fillAfter`. Check the answer. Thanks for your contribution.